# The Result is line 9. NameError: name 'total' is not defined.what should i do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods, python-requests

```
arg1 = int(input("a"))
arg2 = int(input("b"))
def sum( arg1, arg2 ):
  
   total = arg1 + arg2
   print ("Inside the function : ", total)
   return total
   
z = total * total
print(z)
```

Comment: You've never called your function! Do `total = sum( arg1, arg2)` before `z = total * total`.

Comment: thanq you sir..

Answer (score 0):

You never actually call the `sum` function you defined, so the code inside never executes. Try something like this:

```
arg1 = int(input("a"))
arg2 = int(input("b"))

# Here we define the function
def sum(arg1, arg2):
    total = arg1 + arg2
    print("Inside the function : ", total)
    return total

# Here we get the result of the function, and assign it to total
total = sum(arg1, arg2)
z = total * total
print(z)
```

*Note that the `total` variable inside the function is different from the `total` variable inside the function.*